# Control Panel Applet Execution Command Line Syntax

Tags: command-line, control-panel, rundll32.exe, win32, shell32.dll

I'm trying to invoke Internet Options Control Panel applet through command line (Run dialogue).
Specifically, the "Connections" tab.

I used the following syntax:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL INETCPL.CPL,,4
```

Which worked fine. My question is 2-fold:

1. For the "Control_RunDLL" function, what is the 2nd parameter it takes?

(In my cases, and in all the documentation I found, it's NULL or empty)
(1st parameter being the applet name, and the 3rd being the tab number)

2. Where can I access Microsoft documentation that specifically mentions the 2nd parameter?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around some more, turns out a .cpl (a control panel item)[1] file can contain multiple applets (of which enumeration starts from 0).

The 2nd parameter is for the applet index number within a .cpl file, then the 3rd parameter is for the tab index number within the specific applet (as mentioned in my question).

References:

[1] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-control-panel-cpl-files-4dc809cd-5063-6c6d-3bee-d3f18b2e0176

[2] https://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/06/quick-start-to-rundll32-syntax-and-example/

[3] [https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WinBatch/Launching~WinBatch~and~Other~Apps/Control~Panel+Running~Control~Panel~Applets.txt](https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WinBatch/Launching%7EWinBatch%7Eand%7EOther%7EApps/Control%7EPanel+Running%7EControl%7EPanel%7EApplets.txt)

[4] [https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~mgoetsch/cali/Windows%20Configuration/Windows%20Configuration%20Html/UsingRundll32toRunControlPanelApplets.htm](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Emgoetsch/cali/Windows%20Configuration/Windows%20Configuration%20Html/UsingRundll32toRunControlPanelApplets.htm)

[5] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj/nf-shlobj-shruncontrolpanel

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.